# If sets $A$,$B$ are closed, convex sets, they have the same boundary and their interiors intersection is non-empty, does $A=B$?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

If sets $A$,$B$ in Euclidean space are closed, convex sets, they have the same boundary and their interiors intersection is non-empty, can we say $A=B$? Any suggestions and comments are welcome!

Comment: Convex sets are always path-connected and in particular connected.

Comment: When you say Euclidean space, do you mean $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some finite $d$?

Comment: First, drop the word connected, the answer is yes try  to prove your statement by contradiction

Comment: Didn't you asked this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3757598/75923) already?

Comment: I have asked a weaker condition case already. When I say Euclidean space, I mean Rd for some finite d.

Comment: @longjianli The questions seem indiscernible right now.

Comment: @drhab in the previous question he originally didn't require the sets to be convex, so the answer was "no"

Comment: This answer is about "$A,B $are closed set". But I want to show the case that "A,B are closed, convex sets"

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I think he just edited his previous question after it was answered, and the answer there is an answer to a different question

Comment: @Berci This alone doesn’t suffice here now, does it? The premise about the interiors is only that the interiors of $A$ and $B$ meet nontrivially, not that they are the same. Surely it suffices now to show that these are the same, but this is nontrivial,

Comment: I just edited his previous question after it was answered, and the answer there is an answer to a different question .

Comment: @longjianlii it would probably be a good idea to revert back to the original formulation over there in order to avoid confusion

Comment: Thank you @Cronus

Comment: @drhab Same question two times.

Answer (score 5):

It is enough to show $A^\circ \subset B^\circ$, since the opposite inclusion follows by symmetry.    Note that $A^\circ$ is convex (easy exercise) and therefore connected.  Also, $A^\circ$ does not intersect $\partial A = \partial B$ and therefore $A^\circ$ is covered by the disjoint open sets $B^\circ$, $(B^c)^\circ$.  Since $A^\circ$ has nonempty intersection with $B^\circ$, we must have $A^\circ \subset B^\circ$.

---

Previous version (a little longer but maybe easier to visualize):

Let $a \in A$; we will try to show $a \in B$.  If $a \in \partial A = \partial B$ we are done because $B$ is closed and thus $\partial B \subset B$.  So assume $a \in A^\circ$ (the interior of $A$).

By assumption there exists a point $x \in A^\circ \cap B^\circ$.  Consider the line segment $L$ joining $x$ to $a$.  If we take small open neighborhoods $U_a, U_x$ around $a,x$ that are contained in $A$, then their convex hull is open, contained in $A$, and contains $L$.  So every point of $L$ is an interior point of $A$.  Now if $a$ were not in $B$, then since $L$ is connected, it would intersect $\partial B = \partial A$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is yes, going by the complicated tool of Krein-Milman theorem.
Assume for now that they are both bounded, then they are compact and by the Krein-Milman theorem it is enough to see that $\text{ext}(A)=\text{ext}(B)$. This is indeed the case since an extreme point of a convex set in in the boundary, [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2159275/extreme-point-of-a-convex-set-is-also-a-bounday-point).

You can then define $A_n$ and $B_n$ by $A_n:=A\cap \{x\in \mathbb{R}^d: \; \Vert x\Vert\leq n \}$ and $B_n:=B\cap \{x\in \mathbb{R}^d: \; \Vert x\Vert\leq n \}$.

Since $A=\cup A_n$ and $B=\cup B_n$, it is enough to see that $A_n=B_n$. $A_n$ and $B_n$ are bounded, closed convex sets, so the first case applies, and $A_n=B_n$. You just need to verify that $\text{ext}(A_n)=\text{ext}(B_n)$.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with ext. Can you show how to prove ext($A_n$)=ext($B_n$)? Thank you very much!

Comment: @longjianli Well that's a little complicated for me to write, but I'll try to write an edit explaining it.

Comment: Thank you @Keen-ameteur !

Comment: I think there is significant work to be done in the last part, showing that $A_n, B_n$ have the same extreme points.  This is going to have to use the assumption that the interiors of $A,B$ intersect, which hasn't been used yet and which is essential, but I don't see how to use it.

Comment: An extreme point is in the boundary, but not vice versa, so I'm not sure I understand your proof for the compact case...